# Printing (file) information at the bottom line

Tags: command-line, external-command, statusline

I'd like to print some file information on vim's bottom line upon pressing a keyboard shortcut, sort of like `Ctrl+G` but with different info (modification timestamp).

How can I output there?

My current shot:

```
nnoremap <C-H> :!stat -c '\%y' %<CR>
```

is unsatisfactory because it switches to the command output buffer (or what should I call it) and stays there until Enter is pressed, which is quite disruptive.

Comment: You could `:echo systemlist()` or do some processing in a dedicated function. Or use `getftime()`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Most helpful. Thanks! Figured out how to do it based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble)'s suggestion,

```
nnoremap <C-H> :echo systemlist("stat -c '%y' " . expand("%"))[0]<CR>
```

works.